# DiscordJS Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Tags: javascript, logging, discord.js

I am attempting to log when someone joins vc and moves vc, the moving vc logging works well but when joining  a vc it gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')`

```
module.exports = async (client, oldState, newState) => {
        if (oldState.channel && newState.channel && oldState.channel.id !== newState.channel.id) {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor({ name: newState.member.user.tag, iconURL: newState.member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
                .setTimestamp()
                .setColor(config.colour)
                .setFooter({ text: newState.guild.name, iconURL: newState.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }) })
                .setDescription(`**${newState.member} moved from \`${oldState.channel.name}\` to \`${newState.channel.name}\`**`)
            return logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
        }
        if (!oldState.channel.id && newState.channel.id) {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor({ name: newState.member.user.tag, iconURL: newState.member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) })
                .setTimestamp()
                .setColor(config.colour)
                .setFooter({ text: newState.guild.name, iconURL: newState.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }) })
                .setDescription(`** ${newState.member} has joined \`${newState.channel.name}\` channel.**`)
            return logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the first time joining the channel, there's no oldState.channel so bot can't fetch id of a channel which is not exist. You can edit your statements like;

```js
if (oldState.channel && newState.channel && oldState.channel.id !== newState.channel.id)
```

to

```js
if(oldState.channel && newState.channel){
if(oldState.channel.id != newState.channel.id){
 // rest of code
}
}
```

maybe you can make more clean but this is how it works.